# java error message null pointer exception

Tags: java

This is the error i received when i tried running my code below. my teacher said we could ask anywhere for help. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Practise_Assessment.main(Practise_Assessment.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

here is my code if it is needed

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Practise_Assessment {

    public static String absences(String prompt) {// user input for name and
    // days absent
        System.out.println(prompt);
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        return keyboard.nextLine();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int numDayEntries ;
        int numNameEntries;
        int[] daysArray = null ;
        String[] nameArray = null ;

        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("enter # to stop");
            String absences = absences("enter name of person absent then the amount of days they were absent");// the value of the users input

            for(numDayEntries =0; numDayEntries < daysArray.length;numDayEntries++ ){
                daysArray = new int[numDayEntries];
            }
            for(numNameEntries = 0; numNameEntries < nameArray.length;numNameEntries++ ){

                nameArray = new String[numNameEntries];    
            }

            if (absences.equalsIgnoreCase("#")) {
                done = true;    
            } else {
                String DaysAbsent =absences.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "") ;
                int daysAbsent = ((Number) NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(DaysAbsent)).intValue();//   converts a string to an int
                String absentee = absences.replaceAll("\\d", "");// replace all digits in the user input to nothing leaving just the name

                daysArray[numDayEntries] = daysAbsent; 
                nameArray[numNameEntries] = absentee;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(daysArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Daysarray variable is null

Comment: thanks everyone who replied, you guys(and girls) helped so much

Comment: @user3023714  then, you should accept the answer which helped you to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is counting to `daysArray.length`, but `daysArray` is `null`. Furthermore, your `for` loops don't make any sense anyway; you're creating and then throwing away lots of identical arrays. It's very unclear what your code is trying to accomplish, since you're asking for a *single* person's name and then a *single* number indicating the number of absences.

The recommended approach is to (1) use an object that contains both the student's name and the number of absences, keeping this information together in a single record and (2) use a `List` instead of an array if you don't know how many items you're going to need, since a `List` is of variable size.

Answer (score 1):

`daysArray` is null and `.length` is accessed from null reference. That's the cause of `NPE`.You need to initialize array before it is being used. Your `for` loop is not making any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is telling you that the problem is on line 35 of the Practise_Assessment class. You need to look at that line.

If line 35 is this:

```
for(numDayEntries =0; numDayEntries < daysArray.length;numDayEntries++ ){
```

then it is probably because you did not initialise daysArray - you set it to null.

Answer (score 1):

daysArray is null 
numNameEntries IS NULL

Answer (score 1):

Issues in your for loop. Your arrays are set to NULL.

1. Initialize your array before going to use.

   Then try it , you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the cause of the exception - `for(numDayEntries =0; numDayEntries < daysArray.length;numDayEntries++ )`.

Look at the exception you got - NULL-PointerException or NPE. It tells us that some REFERENCE or TYPE has been set as NULL, that is, we did not assign an appropriate object to it. Eg. `Car nfs = null;`. We should have done `Car nfs = new Car();`

Now, the only OBJECT in the error causing line is `daysArray`. Everything else is an int.
So, you should see the rest of your code if `daysArray` is being assigned an object properly or not. Maybe you forgot or maybe the it happens due to a logical error.

Long winded way, but I did it since you are new.